# How to run the container every day at a certain time

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can I configure the image of the container to run every day at 03:00 am. I created an image with node.js

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "./src/update.js" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cronjob on the host:

```
0 3 * * * docker run ....
```